# JavaScript helps with conditional syntax

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a function that calls an API (let's call it API-1) to get the song lyrics.
Since this API sometimes can't find a song in its database, I want to call another API (let's call it API-2) to do the same search.

I need to integrate the code of both APIs inside the function, when the first one doesn't get data.

I tell you some very important information:

In **API-1** I must force the data to be fetched as **XML** and the **responseType** must be 'document'.

**API-2** does not require any of the above conditions, the data is parced as **JSON** and the responseType it supports is 'text', but does not require it to be set, with 'document' it DOES NOT work, it gives error.

Now I will share the function code for API-1 and then I will share the same function code for API-2.

**They both work perfect if I test them independently**.

The help I am asking for is to integrate API-2 when API-1 does not fetch data.

**Code using API-1**

```
this.refreshLyric = function (currentSong, currentArtist) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('GET', proxy_URL + api_URL + 'apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist=' + currentArtistE + '&song=' + ucwords(currentSongE), true);

        // ONLY FOR THIS XMLHttpRequest responseType must be empty string or 'document'
        xhr.responseType = 'document';

        // ONLY FOR THIS XMLHttpRequest force the response to be parsed as XML
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

        xhr.onload = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                                
                var openLyric = document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0];
                var lyric = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Lyric')[0].innerHTML;
                        
                //check if any data was obtained    
                if (lyric != '') {
                    document.getElementById('lyric').innerHTML = lyric.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
                    openLyric.style.opacity = "1";
                    openLyric.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
                } else { /////// HERE INTEGRATE  API-2 //////
                    openLyric.style.opacity = "0.3";
                    openLyric.removeAttribute('data-toggle');

                    var modalLyric = document.getElementById('modalLyrics');
                    modalLyric.style.display = "none";
                    modalLyric.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
                    (document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0]) ? document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0].remove(): '';
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].style.opacity = "0.3";
                document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].removeAttribute('data-toggle');
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

**The same code using API-2**

```
this.refreshLyric = function (currentSong, currentArtist) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                var openLyric = document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0];
                var lyric = data.mus[0].text;
                
                //check if any data was obtained
                if (lyric != '') {
                    document.getElementById('lyric').innerHTML = lyric.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
                    openLyric.style.opacity = "1";
                    openLyric.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
                } else {
                    openLyric.style.opacity = "0.3";
                    openLyric.removeAttribute('data-toggle');

                    var modalLyric = document.getElementById('modalLyrics');
                    modalLyric.style.display = "none";
                    modalLyric.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
                    (document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0]) ? document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0].remove(): '';
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].style.opacity = "0.3";
                document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].removeAttribute('data-toggle');
            }
        }
        xhttp.open('GET', 'https://api.vagalume.com.br/search.php?apikey=' + API_KEY + '&art=' + currentArtist + '&mus=' + currentSong.toLowerCase(), true);
        xhttp.send()
    }
```

The shared codes are of the SAME function (this.refreshLyric), what has to be integrated is only the XMLHttpRequest API.

In the ELSE of line 23 of API-1 I must integrate the code of API-2.

I have already tried it in several ways but I am presented with **syntax problems with the IF - ELSE conditionals** and errors with the API-2 which is getting the responseType and the MimeType of API-1.

Comment: isn't your check supposed to be ```if (lyric == '') ```

Comment: If you're getting response and mime type of API-1 in API-2 then I don't think you're initializing your `XMLHttpRequest` again, you need to do `new XMLHttpRequest()` before calling API-2.

Comment: @ewong, I have already edited that was a mistake. Thx

Comment: @crimson589, I have made a new `XMLHttpRequest`, in fact I have copied all the API-2 code.

Comment: @Juan can you show the code that's combined.

Comment: Fixed I have created another function to call API-2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

**FIXED:** When API-1 cannot find the lyric, I have created a new function that calls API-2. `refreshLyric2(currentSong, currentArtist);` :)

```
    this.refreshLyric = function (currentSong, currentArtist) {
                
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
                xhr.open('GET', proxy_URL + api_URL + 'apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist=' + currentArtistE + '&song=' + ucwords(currentSongE), true);
        
                // ONLY FOR THIS XMLHttpRequest responseType must be empty string or 'document'
                xhr.responseType = 'document';
        
                // ONLY FOR THIS XMLHttpRequest force the response to be parsed as XML
                xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        
                xhr.onload = function () {
                  if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                                        
                        var openLyric = document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0];
                        var lyric = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Lyric')[0].innerHTML;
                                
                        //check if any data was obtained    
                        if (lyric != '') {
                            document.getElementById('lyric').innerHTML = lyric.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
                            openLyric.style.opacity = "1";
                            openLyric.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
                        } else {
                            //If lyric was not obtained, we call API-2
                            refreshLyric2(currentSong, currentArtist);
                        }
                    } else {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].style.opacity = "0.3";
                        document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].removeAttribute('data-toggle');
                    }
                };
                xhr.send();
}
            
                refreshLyric2 = function (currentSong, currentArtist) {
                    
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        
                        var openLyric = document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0];
                        var lyric = data.mus[0].text;
                        
                        //check if any data was obtained
                        if (lyric != '') {
                            document.getElementById('lyric').innerHTML = lyric.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
                            openLyric.style.opacity = "1";
                            openLyric.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
                        } else {
                            openLyric.style.opacity = "0.3";
                            openLyric.removeAttribute('data-toggle');
        
                            var modalLyric = document.getElementById('modalLyrics');
                            modalLyric.style.display = "none";
                            modalLyric.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
                            (document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0]) ? document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0].remove(): '';
                        }
                    } else {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].style.opacity = "0.3";
                        document.getElementsByClassName('lyrics')[0].removeAttribute('data-toggle');
                    }
                }
                xhttp.open('GET', 'https://api.vagalume.com.br/search.php?apikey=' + API_KEY + '&art=' + currentArtist + '&mus=' + currentSong.toLowerCase(), true);
                xhttp.send()
            }
```